# Convert hex stream to arabic language string

Tags: python, hex

I have a problem i never faced before... I have to convert an hex stream received, for example:

20d8a7d986d98a20d985d8a720d8a7d8b9d8b1d98120d8b4d986d98820d98ad8b9d986d98a20d8a7d984d8acd986d8a7d8ad20d8a7d984d8b9d8b3d983d8b1d98a20d984d98a20d8add8b2d8a820d8a7d984d8afd8b9d988d8a920
(binascii.hexlify output...)

To arabic language string.

Any clue or link to start?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> hexstring = "20d8a7d986d98a20d985d8a720d8a7d8b9d8b1d98120d8b4d986d98820d98ad8b9d986d98a20d8a7d984d8acd986d8a7d8ad20d8a7d984d8b9d8b3d983d8b1d98a20d984d98a20d8add8b2d8a820d8a7d984d8afd8b9d988d8a920"
>>> print binascii.unhexlify(hexstring.encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8")
 اني ما اعرف شنو يعني الجناح العسكري لي حزب الدعوة
```

Comment: You also need brackets in order to call `print()`, unless you want to use the old Python 2 dialect.